# App manifest validation error in background tasks

Tags: uwp

To get my app run in the background indefinitely, I modified the code in the manifest file as follows:

```
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="extendedBackgroundTaskTime"/>  
</Capabilities>
```

Which yields the following error:

> The app manifest must be valid as per schema:  Line 45, Column 4,
>   Reason:  Text is not allowed in the context of element

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [What to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally introduced invalid whitespace character in the XML while copying and pasting the `<rescap:Capabilities>` entry to your `Package.appxmanifest`. The invalid character is the whitespace right after the `>` character in your code. You can confirm that by pasting the code to a tool like [this](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php). As you will see, you have a `U+202F` (apparently a [`NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm)) character there:

[image: Invalid Unicode character]

Make sure to delete this "empty space" in the end of the line and the app will compile again :-) .

#### Additional tip - declaring `rescap`

You also need to make sure to include the `rescap` prefix as it is not declared by default. To use restricted capabilities, you must add the necessary namespace declaration to the root `<Package>` element:

```
<Package
    ...
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="... rescap">
```

You need to add the `xmlns:rescap` attribute and also append `rescap` to the end of `IgnorableNamespaces`.